# How to find PHP errors?

Tags: php, error-handling

How can I find out what errors are there on the page I'm viewing?

I'm getting one of the following:

- A blank white page
- 500 Internal Server Error page

And not the actual error! I can't debug!

---

How can I tell the actual error that happened on the page?